# How to post back on multi select dropdown change event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, multi-select

I have Asp.net website in which i need a multi select dropdown and on click/on selection change i need to do a post back.

So far i know of Jquery multi select dropdown but in jquery multi select dropdown , they have on change event but in client side.

So how can i achieve this functionality with multiselect option and on select change do a post back.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: on the client side event initiate a ajax post to do a post back. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically do a postback by calling the `__doPostBack` function, passing the name of the requesting control as a parameter. So what you can do is use a statement similar to this:

```
__doPostBack('name$of$the$select$control');
```

Just hook a function to the jQuery change event, and make it run the above line. Just make sure you are using the right name for the control.